# How can I get my Vega marks to update when a signal changes?

Tags: vega

I am using Vega to plot a bar chart. I also have a drop down list 'signal' that is used to specify the sort order of the data:

```
...

  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "sortby",
      "value": "name",
      "bind": {"input": "select", "options": ["name", "net_worth"]}
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "people",
      "values": [
        {"name": "Grimes", "net_worth": 1.2},
        {"name": "Johnny", "net_worth": 6},
        {"name": "Elon", "net_worth": 100},
        {"name": "Amber", "net_worth": 0.1}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "collect",
          "sort": {"field": {"signal": "sortby"}, "order": "ascending"}
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
...
```

The sort transform is working correctly, when the chart is initially rendered, the data is sorted according to the default sort value of 'name'.

When I change the selected sortby value I see that the 'people' data is correctly sorted (I can see this by inspecting the Data Viewer tab in the Vega editor), however the marks do not update.

[image: screenshot of vega editor]

I've made sure that the `encode.update` definition for the marks holds all the positional data. I'm a bit stumped as to why the chart doesn't update, it feels like it's probably just due to a simple oversight by me and I'm hoping that someone here can spot what the issue is!

The full code is pasted below and is also available in the editor: [Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-j+Y7QZakRzOKMhwD6dD6iBCJgXhEEESEYSYW0bStEAA)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 400,
  "padding": 5,
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "sortby",
      "value": "name",
      "bind": {"input": "select", "options": ["name", "net_worth"]}
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "people",
      "values": [
        {"name": "Grimes", "net_worth": 1.2},
        {"name": "Johnny", "net_worth": 6},
        {"name": "Elon", "net_worth": 100},
        {"name": "Amber", "net_worth": 0.1}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "collect",
          "sort": {"field": {"signal": "sortby"}, "order": "ascending"}
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "people", "field": "name"},
      "range": "height",
      "padding": 0.1
    },
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "domain": {"data": "people", "field": "net_worth"},
      "nice": true,
      "range": "width"
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {"orient": "top", "scale": "xscale"},
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale"},
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "yscale"}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "people"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {"fill": {"value": "steelblue"}},
        "update": {
          "height": {"scale": "yscale", "band": 1},
          "width": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "net_worth"},
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "value": 0},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "name"}
        },
        "exit": {"width": {"scale": "xscale", "value": 0}}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently an open bug as described here: https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/1417. You can register your interest on that page to see when it will be fixed. In the meantime, I have used the workaround described to get the functionality you're after.

[Editor.](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-N2MhZvaFFUcaMiQREah1kE2H4bhp40YGkRzFydZwFmdD2qRCLkfxlGCSEYRcW0bStEAA)

[image]

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 400,
  "padding": 5,
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "sortby",
      "value": "name",
      "bind": {"input": "select", "options": ["name", "net_worth"]}
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "people",
      "values": [
        {"name": "Grimes", "net_worth": 1.2},
        {"name": "Johnny", "net_worth": 6},
        {"name": "Elon", "net_worth": 100},
        {"name": "Amber", "net_worth": 0.1}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "window",
          "sort": {"field": {"signal": "sortby"}},
          "ops": ["row_number"],
          "fields": [null],
          "as": ["rank"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {
        "data": "people",
        "field": "name",
        "sort": {"field": "rank", "op": "min"}
      },
      "range": "height",
      "padding": 0.1
    },
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "domain": {"data": "people", "field": "net_worth"},
      "nice": true,
      "range": "width"
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {"orient": "top", "scale": "xscale"},
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale"},
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "yscale"}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "people"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {"fill": {"value": "steelblue"}},
        "update": {
          "height": {"scale": "yscale", "band": 1},
          "width": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "net_worth"},
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "value": 0},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "name"}
        },
        "exit": {"width": {"scale": "xscale", "value": 0}}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```